# Combine vector and raster tiles

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, mbtiles, vector-tiles

I have raster tiles in mbtiles format.
I also have vector tiles in GeoJson format.
My goal is to combine both tiles so they will overlap each other, the vector tiles will be on top of the raster tiles.
I am using QGIS to import both layers of tiles and can't find a way to make them overlap.

Comment: Do they have the same CRS?

Comment: yes. I use EPSG 4326

Comment: So what happens when you add both layers?